# pd.crosstab() inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Suppose I have the following dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x','y','z','x','x'],'col2':['n1','n2',np.nan,'n3','n2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x','y','z','x','x'],'col2':['m1','m2',np.nan,'m3','m2']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x','y','z','x','x'],'col2':['o1','o2',np.nan,'o3','o2']})
df_list = [df1,df2,df3]
```

I want to make a crosstab on each element of `df_list` as follow:

```
pd.crosstab(df_list[i]['col1'], df_list[i]['col2'].isna())
```

If I replace `i` by `0,1` or `2` I get the right table. Now I wish to put this in a for loop, namely:

```
crosstab_list = []
for i in df_list:
    crosstab_list.append(pd.crosstab(df_list[i]['col1'], df_list[i]['col2'].isna()))
```

yet I get the following error,

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame
```

I wonder what am I missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking to much:

```
crosstab_list = []
for i in df_list:
    crosstab_list.append(pd.crosstab(i['col1'], i['col2'].isna()))
```